# Spring Data mongodb: how to add credentials when running a replica set

Tags: mongodb, authentication, credentials, spring-data-mongodb

I'm running MongoDB 2.2. I can add credentials to access my single instance MongoDB like this:

```
<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
  <property name="writeResultChecking" value="EXCEPTION"/>
  <property name="writeConcern" value="FSYNC_SAFE"/>
  <constructor-arg ref="myRs"/>
  <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="mydb"/>
  <constructor-arg name="userCredentials" ref="userCredentials"/>
</bean>

<bean id="userCredentials" class="org.springframework.data.authentication.UserCredentials">
  <constructor-arg name="username" value="username" />
  <constructor-arg name="password" value="password" />
</bean>
```

but the docs say that only keyfile authentication is available for replica sets: 
http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/administration/replica-sets/#replica-set-security

How can I use DB credentials preferrably (or even a keyfile) in the app context XML file so I can authenticate to the MongoDB replica set when using Spring Data MongoDB?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--keyfile option enables key based authentication between replicaset members. It has no effect the communication between your application and the replicaset.

You need to add a user to the database. Make sure you are connected to Primary.

```
$ mongo
PRIMARY> use the_database_i_want_to_be_authenticated
switched to db the_database_i_want_to_be_authenticated
PRIMARY> db.addUser("myusername","mypassword")
{
    "user" : "myusername",
    "readOnly" : false,
    "pwd" : "a6de521abefc2fed4f5876855a3484f5",
    "_id" : ObjectId("5194932444ef978a730c22d4")
}
```

After you created a user in the database, you will be able to connect it with the following

```
<bean id="userCredentials" class="org.springframework.data.authentication.UserCredentials">
    <constructor-arg name="username" value="username" />
    <constructor-arg name="password" value="password" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks. I did add the "auth=true" line to /etc/mongodb.conf on the primary and restarted it. I then added the user through the shell  the way you show. So I expected I would be challenged for credentials the next time I user mongo shell to connect to the primary but I was not. Am I missing something?

Comment: you will not be asked the credentials unless you switch to the authenticated database. even if you switched you won't be prompted for username/password. But if you try to run any command such as show collections, it will show you authentication error. You need to write db.auth('your_username','your_password')

Comment: you can connect to mongo shell by giving the user name and password too.. $ mongo your_db_name -u username -p